# How change via ajax part of the form validated by JsFormValidatorBundle

Tags: symfony, validation

My form is validated by JsFormValidatorBundle. I have to replace only part of the existing form via ajax. Specifically I change the payment list according to the chosen transport in an order process. init_js_validation() works well but the form is still validating by binded "submitForm" at the first time and next ajax accumulates another event.

Then I have already modified FpJsFormValidator.attachDefaultEvent and i have remove old binding. The form is still validated according to origin model and new payments are validated after marking form as invalid.

FpJsFormValidator.constraintsCounter is increased by every init_js_validation(). Model is ok but constraints are accumulated.

Can I reset or destroy a validation of this form or remove constraints before init_js_validation()?